# Still getting '403 Forbidden: You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints' after upgrading to Basic

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I just subscribed to the Twitter API Basic plan in order to get trending data. Here's what my code looks like:

```
trends_result = api.get_place_trends(1)
for (trend_num, trend) in enumerate(trends_result[0]["trends"]):
    print(trend["name"])
    print(trend["tweet_volume"])
```

When I try to run the above code block, I get the error:

> Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
> 453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product

I tried regenerating my api and access tokens/secrets, but I still got the error.
This is in Jupyter notebook and I'm on tweepy version 4.14.0.
How do I solve this issue?